# Show that if two right cosets $Ha$ and $Hb$ are distinct then two left cosets $a^{-1}H$ and $b^{-1}H$ are distinct

Tags: abstract-algebra

I can not understand that how it is proved, so please somebody help me. I unable to prove but I think you will able to prove it.

Comment: One way is to show that $Ha\to a^{-1}H$ is a bijection (or for this just injection is enough) between left and right cosets

Comment: Please prove in details.

Comment: is this about groups?

Comment: Yes this is about group

Answer (score 1):

As $Ha,Hb$ are equivalence classes, $Ha\neq Hb \iff a\notin Hb\iff ab^{-1}\notin H\iff (ab^{-1})^{-1}=ba^{-1}\notin H\iff a^{-1}\notin b^{-1}H\iff a^{-1}H\neq b^{-1}H$